Why gradio image resizes the image in one environment?
I am running the same gradio script in two different computers.
It uses
image_display = gr.Image(label="Image Display", interactive=False)

however in one PC it shows the image occupying all the width of the Image element, and in the other, the image appears smaller

I don't know why this is happening (except maybe a difference of the gradio versions), but how can I make it explicitly that the image element have a width so that the image occupies everything?
EDIT: Turns out it was the gradio version
When I tried a different environment with 4.40.0 it showed the figure in full
Now the question is, with the latest gradio how can I configure gr.Image to display the figure in full?

Do both monitors have the same high resolution? On the left side it is 2K and the right side is 4K.

@toyotaSupra I am displaying them in the same monitor. One  is a remote machine

Turns out it was the gradio version....
